# Calculate Skewness and Kurtosis of $ Y = \frac{X-np}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $X \sim \textrm{Binom}(n,p)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The only clue I have is that $E[g(x)]=\sum_{k\geq 0}^{}{g(k)P[X=k]}$

Comment: What is $g$ for skewness and kurtosis?

Comment: What do you mean by $g$?

Comment: From your formula $\mathbb E[g(X)]$ - what is the function $g$ corresponding to skewness and to kurtosis?

Comment: Oh that is just a general rule, for all functions. In this case one could use $g(X)=(\frac{X-np}{\sqrt{n}}$. Using this I have been able to reduce the problem to showing the skewness and kurtosis for a binomial distribution which can be found on wikipedia, though I have no idea how to prove that.